# php how to remove evil characters from string

Tags: php, special-characters, file-get-contents

I am using *file_get_contents* to get some remote text, and the text contains left/right double quoted text such as `“Green Slime”`.

*file_get_contents* returns this text as `�Green Slime�`.

Looking at the remote source, the `“”` characters are literal, not entity codes. There is no character set definition in the source.

Is there a context that I can add to *file_get_contents* to correct this? If not, how can I *str_replace* these characters?

EDIT: Obvious solutions like htmlentities() and str_replace() do not work. I also get the same characters returned when using cURL.

Comment: How about htmlentities? I am not sure. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `ord()` to determine that these characters are chr(147) and chr(148), then used `str_replace( Chr(147), "&#147", $str )`.

Not sure why both file_get_contents and curl return this content in a way that can't be displayed in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put this immediately under the `head` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: I already have that in my page. I Can't change the remote page.

Comment: You can use a string replacer then to replace those parenthesis with some others for example: $s = str_replace('“', '"', $s); echo $s;

Answer (score 0):

HTML Entities.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This will solve you problem and fix the output.

Comment: htmlentities does not convert them.

Answer (score -1):

Look into utf8_decode/encode functions

Comment: UTF-8 isn't the only charset with these quotes.